# Grafana + elastic, find ratio of queries

Tags: elasticsearch, grafana

I'm trying to find a ratio of users that have some attribute versus those that do not.

I assume, if it is possible at all, I'd have to use the inline scripting option. I am unable to figure out (or find good documentation), what are the limitations of inline scripts. Can it be used for [mapreduce](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-scripted-metric-aggregation.html)?

Has someone figured out, how to find ratio between counts in grafana, using elastic as the datasource?

Comment: have you found any solution?

Comment: I'am looking for a solution to this question too